# Kneading dough with long nails; latex gloves?

Tags: dough

Is it possible/recommended to knead dough with disposable latex gloves on?

I'm asking because I have quite long nails and don't find it a very hygienic idea to knead dough with long nails. Not to mention the amount of dough I'd have to pick out from under my nails later on...

Will it transfer any smell/taste to the dough?
Would washing your hands with the gloves on change this?

Comment: Sort of tangential to your question, but kneading is done primarily with the palms. I just tried this... with a bench scraper, a little care and good technique, you don't have to use your fingertips at all.

Comment: @RobertCartaino I guess you're right, if I used a spoon or something to put it in the palm of my hand my fingertips wouldn't even need to touch the dough. Good point, thanks!

Comment: Typically you drop it down onto a floured board. The rest is done almost entirely with the heal of your outstretched hands as you kneed, and your palms as your cup your hands to form the dough into the desired shape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are your fingernails involved in kneading? I've made bread regularly since I was 16, time off for college when I had no kitchen at my disposal, but that's still 30 years of making bread. You should be kneading with the open ball of your hand, and your nails should not be involved at all. My nails are always out-turned, with the bread dough beneath my palms. I can't imagine wearing gloves for kneading; the whole experience of knowing when the bread is sufficiently kneaded has to do with the *feel* of the dough, and your hand will not be sensitive to that with gloves on.

Comment: I'm not making bread, I'm making cookies. I have no cooking experience at all and I have always kneaded cookie dough with mostly my fingers. Not to mention scooping dough from the bowl etc. However I did manage to knead the dough without it touching my fingernails, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Long nails will puncture smooth thin latex gloves (the surgical type) very quickly, especially during something like kneading where the gloves slide against your fingers all the time. Thick latex gloves, like the one for washing dishes, will be more durable, but they are also grippy and a lot of dough will stick. Also, they are usually not food safe.

If you really need something, I guess clear wide plastic gloves, like the ones in hair colorant packs, will work better, but I don't know where you can get them as explicitly food safe.

Personally, I would just knead barehanded. The underside of long nails can be washed just as easily as the upper side, and nobody finds it unhygienic to have the upper side of nails (short or long) touch dough. The real problem would come if you keep short nails and cannot remove the dirt which sticks between the nailtip and the meat of the finger. Long nails are much easier in that regard.

Comment: There's a variety of these that are a bit more durable and specifically made for food service, unsurprisingly called "food service gloves" - any restaurant supply store should have them.

Answer (score 2):

Get food grade disposable latex gloves.  Some times they use the term food safe.

There are also dough gloves [image: dough gloves]

Comment: But will they leave some sort of smell or taste?

Comment: @Kareen I guess if  they were poorly made.  I expect something call food save to not impart smell or taste.

Comment: Sometimes I wish they didn't invent them. 50% of the street food sellers (here) seem to think it's for their protection: They touch everything (hair, cash machine, whatever) while wearing gloves and making my stuff, and when they're done, they remove them (boo! don't want those germs!). Subtle hints/suggestions, hints/suggestions, and requests don't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

I make my bread in my Kitchenaid mixer. I only use my hands to shape the dough before putting it into the tin, or onto a baking sheet. My nails, whether long or short, don't get any dough under then, as I only use the heel of my palm for the handling process.

Comment: I usually do this as well but I have no machines to use atm because I'm moving house.